# Display the Data Just like default contactsVIew in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, contacts

I want to create a activity which should display my data same as the default contactView in android. Below is the snapshot . I want UI same as the image below.[image]

a search box and all the alphabets at the right hand side of UI.

My data is coming from webservice and i want to display it just like default android contactsView

Answer (score 0):

this is quite an old style of how the contacts app look like.

anyway, what you can do is to use [**pinnedHeaderListView**](https://github.com/JimiSmith/PinnedHeaderListView) library , and for each item put a simple imageView and textView.

for the tabs, use the tabs navigation as used on [**actionBarSherlock**](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) library

Comment: I dont want image and also the tab. I just want to display my data in this format. a search box and the alphabets at right hand side.

Comment: about the alphabet, it's shown using the pinnedHeaderListView i've mentioned (it shows a letter above each group of contacts) and together with fastScroll, it's very similar. or use this http://www.androidviews.net/2012/10/indexablelistview/ . about the search box, you can use EditText and use filter on the list using getFilter (but you need of course to implement Filterable for the adapter ). i recommend using the search action item (also available in actionBarSherlock library) instead of an editbox, as it's more native and common, and people are more used to it.